# I set up a switch-statement to handle OnClick events in my Activity, but only the first case works. Why?

Tags: android, switch-statement, onclicklistener

I created an empty activity in my Android project, and added one TextView and one Button to it, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    tools:context="com.radical.pillbox.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/CloseActivityCross"
    android:text="@string/cross"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
    android:textColor="@color/pillbox_green_primary_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IntroString"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CloseActivityCross"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Welcome to Pillbox."
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EmailEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/IntroString"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.64"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
    android:hint="email@example.com"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textColor="@color/pillbox_background_dark"
    android:textColorHint="@color/pillbox_accent_green" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/PasswordEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/EmailEditText"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:alpha="0.64"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
    android:hint="password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColor="@color/pillbox_background_dark"
    android:textColorHint="@color/pillbox_accent_green" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/FooterString"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="2018."
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/SignInButton"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/pillbox_green_primary_dark"
    android:layout_below="@id/PasswordEditText"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/SignUpButton"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/pillbox_green_primary_dark"
    android:layout_below="@id/PasswordEditText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/SignInButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My *MainActivity.java* file is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailEditText);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordEditText);
        TextView close = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CloseActivityCross);
        Button sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUpButton);
        Button sign_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignInButton);

        email.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        password.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        sign_in.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        close.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailEditText);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordEditText);
        TextView close = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CloseActivityCross);
        Button sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUpButton);
        Button sign_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignInButton);

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case (R.id.SignInButton):
                    Log.d("Event:", "Signed in with correct credentials.");
                break;

            case (R.id.CloseActivityCross):
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Closing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                Log.d("Cross:", "Activity closed");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In my main activity, I created cases in a switch-statement to handle the OnClick Events, but only the first case defined works. The remaining cases never trigger for some reason or trigger after an extended delay. To diagnose where the problem occurs, I have:
        1. Tried to change the order in which I add the listeners
        2. Changed cases with the first being CloseActivityCross once and SignInButton the next. Each time, only the first case works properly.
 Why does this happen? I should mention that in one trial, things began working perfectly for a while, and now the same issue is cropping up.

Comment: Check field `CloseActivityCross` whats its holding ?

Comment: @ADM I didn't quite get you, I'm sorry. In case this clarifies, the text value for CloseActivityCross is a string resource called "close", which is basically the Unicode character '×' or 'U+00D7'.

Comment: LOL. That i know . you have written in Question ` TextView close = (TextView) findViewById(CloseActivityCross);` . I have asked what is `CloseActivityCross` . Either it should be `R.id.CloseActivityCross` or you have an `int CloseActivityCross` at clas level holding the id .

Comment: @ADM My apologies! Thank you for pointing out the error. It should be `R.id.CloseActivityCross`.

Comment: Ok now we getting somewhere . Could you update the whole layout in question with root  layout.

Comment: Done! I have updated the Java code as well to reflect the complete code for the activity.

Comment: in onclick method why you again definded TextView and Button remove it and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Listeners` are OK in java code . The problem is in xml . Your parent layout is `RelativeLayout` and you have use rule `android:layout_below` .

In some places you have used `"@id` instead of `"@+id` . So this will make overlap the views . Make it write as `"@+id` in all `android:layout_below` tags and remove `android:onClick="onClick"` from root layout . see if it works .
**Suggestion**  :-  If all of your widgets aligned vertically then Use `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation .

Comment: Yes! This works. Why does `@+id` make the difference? I was under the impression that `@+id/` should be used only when the id is assigned the first time.

Comment: +id is supposed to be used only to create new id's. It's not suggestible to create a new reference for already existing views.

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-initialize your views in onClick method i.e., remove these lines from the `OnClick` method and it should be good.

```
    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EmailEditText);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordEditText);
    TextView close = (TextView) findViewById(CloseActivityCross);
    Button sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUpButton);
    Button sign_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignInButton);
```

what's happening is, when you press any of these views, they lose their `onClickListeners` as you are initializing the above views again.

Edited as OP added additional code.

EDIT 2:

Remove `OnClick` for root element RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
tools:context="com.radical.pillbox.MainActivity">
```

Comment: That not a problem at all . You can get views anywhere you want .

Comment: I initially initialised those views again thinking that the scope of those variables would be limited to the `OnClick()` method, in case I needed to change any properties of those views. However, I am not referencing those variables anywhere in the function as of now, and the problem persists even when I remove the repeated code.

Comment: just because you can doesn't mean you should. When the views are re-initialized, they won't have the onClickListeners that were already set.

Comment: @someone Views do not reinitialize with `findViewById()`  . `findViewById()` only does what the name suggest . it finds view with the given id if not found the it returns `null`.